# Spring Boot XML Web Service with NO property names under the root element

Tags: xml, web-services, spring-boot

I have the following entity class in SpringBoot:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "on-demand-pin" )
public class OnDemandPin {

    String onDemandPin;

}
```

which generates the following XML-Output:

```
<on-demand-pin><onDemandPin>1234567890</onDemandPin></on-demand-pin>
```

but I need a output which looks like this:

```
<on-demand-pin>1234567890</on-demand-pin>
```

How can I achieve this? Tried different annotations but nothing worked.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Cheers,

Frank

Answer (score 0):

a colleague found it, I just need to do this and then it works:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "on-demand-pin" )
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE )
public class OnDemandPin {

    @XmlValue
    private String onDemandPin;

}
```